# how to protect videos from being download in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, video

I'm building a Rails app that has videos that users will see on the app and they will pay for it. So I need to ensure that no one can download the video. How can I protect, for example, that someone go to the source code the page and find the link and download it?

Comment: dont put them in public, serve them through a protected action

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do this in standard Rails techniques. If you are serving the file yourself:  [Dirty Web Video Secret: If You Can See It, You Can Steal It](http://wistia.com/blog/dirty-web-video-secret-if-you-can-see-it-you-can-steal-it/)

> You can’t guarantee that a video can’t be copied, but you can make it harder by limiting the people with access to the video, by letting those people know that you can track how they view your videos, and by putting some reasonable technological hurdles in the way.

If you are OK using flash, then you can look at Brightcove's solution that uses "DRM" http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/protecting-your-videos-drm

**What do most people do?**

They use an authenticated URL that expires (to prevent emailing and sharing), and trust their users won't download and share the videos. They then ignore those that do share (or file DCMA takedown requests).